# Writing a double factorial in product notation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need to write an expression for n!! using product notation.

So far I have:

$$n!!=\prod_{k=0}^{?} (2k+1)$$

What I'm confused about is the "?". 
How would you set the upper bound in this case? Would it just be (n-1)/2

I don't think it works for even numbers, but is that okay?

Any help would be appreciated! :)
P.S --> So sorry about notation. Still unsure of how to use this site!

Comment: Have you even just Googled double factorial? Right there on the Wikipedia page, a product formula. Your form isn't going to work if $n$ is even...

Comment: A tutorial for MathJax is [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto)

Comment: Thanks Ross! I'll look into that link before posting from now on.
Thomas -- yes, I googled it. But I refrain from Wikipedia because it's often incorrect. I just wanted to confirm that my work was right. Thanks for editing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your upper bound for odd $n$ would be $(n-1)/2$, so you could have $$n!!=\prod_{k=0}^{(n-1)/2}2k+1$$  It is easier to count down by $2$'s from $n$, as that handles odd and even cases.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much :)